# Threebox how do I get all 3d objects on the map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, threebox

I need to get an array or object with all 3D models that have been added to the Mapbox map, as it is on the screenshot below. How can I get these objects?

[image]

I was trying to do something like this code but it didn't work.

```
const buildings3DModels = map.tb.world.children;
console.log("buildings3DModels: ", buildings3DModels);
buildings3DModels.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

I can see log an array with object with:

```
console.log(map.tb.world.children);
```

[image]

But for some reason I cant loop through the array with for example forEach or any other loops, it's just don't return anything.

So, my question is: How can I get these 3D objects from the map after they were added to the map? and how can I loop through each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm maintaining the [latest threebox repo](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox). `tb.world.children` is a simple array so if `tb.world.children.forEach((o) => { console.log(o) });` is not logging anything is because is empty at the runtime is being executed. Could you post your full code?

If your 3D objects are being loaded through `tb.loadObj` which is a full async method, it's very probable you are trying to access to `tb.world.children` array before the objects are fully loaded. If so, then you should manage the `Promise` instances returned by this method and control when all of them are resolved.

Here you have a method that loads 100 models and logs the objects inside threebox.

```js
function makeNaive(options) {
    let promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
            tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                let lng = origin[0] + Math.random() * 0.4 - 0.2;
                let lat = origin[1] + Math.random() * 0.4 - 0.2;
                let alt = origin[2] + Math.random() * 0.4 - 0.2;
                let obj = model.setCoords([lng, lat, alt]);
                tb.add(obj);

                if (api.animation) {
                    // play default animation, for 10 seconds
                    let opt = { animation: 0, duration: 10000 };
                    obj.playDefault(opt);
                }

                getGeometryTotalLength();
                resolve(true);

            })
        }));

    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        console.log("All promises finished:");
        tb.world.children.forEach((o) => { console.log(o) });
    });
    map.repaint = true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @jscastro! This is exactly what was my problem. Now everything works like I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that, let mw know if you have any other issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but you are using threebox, so here is a fiddle that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/up8j3va5/

Short snip from the fiddle:

```
    threebox.addAtCoordinate(
                    plane, 
                    [origin[0], origin[1], 10],
                    {preScale: 1}
                );
                
    threebox.world.children.forEach(element => 
      console.log(element.position.x, 
                  element.position.y, 
                  element.position.z));
```